# Android Studio > Kotlin > Toast error > E/GraphicExt

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile-application

I'm running a simple counter (counts how much a button is pressed) on my physical device instead of android emulator and everything seems fine except the toast message seems to be faulty, it shows the message, but when i tap the button that triggers the Toast multiple times, the Toast message has a delay on showing between one tap and another.

This is the Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(this,"Works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Also the android studio shows this error:

**E/GraphicExt: GraphicExtModuleLoader::CreateGraphicExtInstance false**

My device is a Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro, running android 10.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmOT0.jpg)

EDIT:

This is the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First app!"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="162dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="162dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="255dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="162dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="162dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:text="Click me!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is the MainActivity:

```
package com.example.helloworld

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var timesClicked = 0

        button.setOnClickListener {
            timesClicked += 1
            textView.text = timesClicked.toString()
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Button works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it says that the linear layout is null, can you post the activity code that you are calling the toast message?

Comment: @beastlyCoder i updated the content

Comment: i'm going to create a project, and test it myself

Comment: @beastlyCoder did you figure it out? i'm thinking the problem might be on my device, since other apps from playstore are having the same toast delay

Comment: I had posted an answer saying it worked on my device, but then deleted it because that wouldn't be of much help to you